# Changing parent component from child components in vue.js

Tags: vue.js

I have a main component called App.vue which contains some html div elements and a router-view. Form a component which is assigned to a route, I want to show/hide a div in App.vue  (If a button is clicked in child component, show one div in parent, show another div for another button,.etc). I tried passing a prop to router-view and update prop prom child, but it shows error. How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can listen to an event in `router-view` tag and act accordingly:

```js
const child = {
  template: `<div style="margin-bottom:100px">
     <button @click="$emit('clicked')">Toggle div</button>
  </div>`
}

const router = new VueRouter({
  routes: [ { path: '/child', component: child } ]
})

new Vue({
  router,
  el: '#app',
  data: { displayMe: 'block' },
  methods: {
    toggleMe: function() {
      this.displayMe = (this.displayMe === 'block') ? 'none' : 'block';
    }
  }
})
```

```css
#hideme {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: orange
}
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue/dist/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue-router/dist/vue-router.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <div>
    <div id="hideme" :style="{display: displayMe}"></div>
  </div>
  <router-link to="/child">Visit child</router-link>
  <router-view @clicked="toggleMe()"></router-view>
</div>
```

For multiple `divs` you can pass some data with events, and receive it in `$event` argument of your handler function (example: `toggleMe($event)`), and resolve style properties individually. You can track each `div` using [ref](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#ref) attribute for example, and save status inside `data` object with structure like `{ '1': 'block', ...}` and retrieve styles using a method.